# Managing CSS in Sencha Touch

Tags: css, sass, sencha-touch, compass-sass

Is there a way to manage the CSS for a Sencha Touch app outside of the framework?

I'm used to working with CodeKit or Grunt to manage dependencies for websites, but with Sencha Touch everything seems to be done within the framework. I'm assuming that as long as everything gets compiled to the resources/css folder then it will be fine. But what about the framework resources? Do they get compiled to the same place or does the app make a separate request for them?

Comment: Thanks Vijeth, you should post this as an answer so that I can accept it!

Comment: CodeKit and Grunt simply manage dependencies so you can set them up to compile the css wherever you like, so it sounds like it should work fine.

Comment: Cool. Posted the answer. Please accept it. And thanks for the info.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea of CodeKit or Grunt. Anyways in Sencha Touch all the CSS files get placed to the resources/css folder after the compilation. It's the same even when we add custom CSS files or use SASS with Compass compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I use codekit too.
This is my solution: CodeKit -> Preferences -> (the left side bar) OTHER TOOLS -> Compass
Then select Use the compass executable at this path and choose the path you install compass